# How can I determine the current font family being used by Sublime Text 2?

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext2

I am using the obsidian colour theme for Notepad++ and Sublime Text 2, but the font is not the same in each.

I prefer the font used by Sublime Text 2 seen in the screenshot below. How can I determine what that font family is so that I can set it in Notepad++?

[image: Comparison of font family in each editor]

Comment: I disagree that it's off topic. While dealing with JavaScript Unicode hell, I was able to paste JSON results from curl (| pbcopy) into Sublime Text2. And the Unicode chars rendered as expected, whereas the Non-ASCII font in iTerm didn't support them.

Comment: This does seem to need re-opening, maybe with some edits because it's not well written. The community defined scope includes "software tools commonly used by programmers" and even point #6 in the off-topic list includes an exception "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

it's **Consolas** , you can view the current font by typing:

```
view.settings().get('font_face')
```

nb: The shortcut for the console is

```
ctrl + `
```

Comment: thank you very much , I download the consolas font and put it in c:\windows\fonts ,but why can not I find this font in notepad++ dropdown select font menu?

Comment: is there a problem with this specific font or you can't find any new added font in the settings->style configurator menu?

Comment: thank you ,it should be the problem of my systerm

Comment: For those that are interested, it is `Menlo Regular` on the Mac Version. (Same as Xcode default I believe).

Comment: Typing... where? What program?